# Identify fibonacci sequences from a set of data

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

Let there be a set of increasing order integer data ${a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, ...}$.
given the increasing infinite sequence of integers, how can we determine whether there is an infinite subsequence which is a subsequence of a shifted fibonacci sequence?

Comment: The sentence in brackets makes no sense.

Comment: Thank you Gerry, I edited it. (I missed the end of the sentence)

Comment: I add here some further thoughts which go some way illustrating the problem. If some of the numbers in the data set are the well known fibonacci numbers then the problem is easier as we can apply the test stated in the brackets for each number in the set, then check if the fibonacci identified numbers are successive. However the data could also have 'shifted' fibonacci sequences $F_k +m$ or a mix of shifts $F_k +q$ (m,q integers).

Comment: What do you mean by "the index of the number data"?

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: Sorry I dont live here....I mean we do not know the number k of $F_k$. Why is that? Because number 3 for example could be k=1 of a sequence shifted by 3, ($F_k+3) $, OR ,   k=4  of   $F_k$

Comment: Basically my observable is known as difference in numbers but I do not know on which spiral branch the data belong to. (If you know what I mean)

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. I don't see any spirals, for starters.

Comment: I'm still trying to make sense of your question. You aren't helping, much. Is this your question: given an increasing infinite sequence of integers, how can we determine whether there is an infinite subsequence which is a subsequence of a shifted fibonacci sequence?

Comment: Yes this can be described as you say. Thanks...

Comment: Good. Then, why don't you edit it so it says that?

Comment: OK IF this helps I have...